# OpenJDK Client VM - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, mapreduce, jvm

I am running Hadoop map reduce job on a cluster.
I am getting this error.

> OpenJDK Client VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x79f20000, 104861696, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>
> Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 104861696 bytes for committing reserved memory.

what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have `swap` space on your machine

```
ubuntu@VM-ubuntu:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           994        928         65          0          1         48
-/+ buffers/cache:        878        115
Swap:         4095       1086       3009
```

notice the `Swap` line.

I just encountered this problem on an Elastic Computing instance. Turned out swap space is not mounted by default.

Comment: A dynamic swap manager is an option: http://pqxx.org/development/swapspace/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the memory allocation size by passing these Runtime Parameters.

For example:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar application.jar
```

- Xmx is the maximum size
- Xms is the minimum size

Answer (score 1):

There can be a container memory overflow with the parameters that you are using for the JVM

Check if the attributes:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

on yarn.xml matches the desired value.

For more memory reference, read the:

[HortonWorks memory reference](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html)

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047879/hadoop-cannot-allocate-memory-java-io-ioexception-error-12)

Note: This is for Hadoop 2.0, if you are running hadoop 1.0 check the Task attributes.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the available memory is less than the jvm required memory which result in "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue".

check your available memory:

```
free -h
```

stop some useless process and get more memory.